# Find logo in images

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am looking for a solution that can identify whether a given logo from one image is present in a set of images. Is this possible with cognitive services, or is there other services that can be used for this?

Comment: There is object detection support in the custom vision service. It sounds like that is what you need.

Comment: Just tested and it is exactly was I was looking for. Thanks. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Microsoft Custom Vision service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/) now has [object detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/csharp-tutorial-od) functionality in it, which should be good for this scenario.